# Simplest way to provide template specialization for derived classes

Tags: c++, template-specialization, inheritance

I have the following scenario:

```
class my_base { ... }

class my_derived : public my_base { ... };


template<typename X>
struct my_traits;
```

I want to specialize `my_traits` for all classes derived from `my_base` including, e.g.:

```
template<typename Y> // Y is derived form my_base.
struct my_traits { ... };
```

I have no problems with adding tags, members to `my_base` to make it simpler. I've seen some tricks but I still feel lost.

How can this be done in a simple and short way?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281725/template-specialization-based-on-inherit-class, if that's good enough.

Comment: @Beta, isn't there simpler way? As I can arbitrary change my_base so maybe it can be done without IsBaseOf?

Comment: Simpler in c++11 : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25934222/1132686

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't need to write your own isbaseof.  You can use boost's or c++0x's.

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

struct base {};
struct derived : base {};

template < typename T, typename Enable = void >
struct traits;

template < typename T >
struct traits< T, typename boost::enable_if<std::is_base_of<base, T>>::type >
{
  enum { value = 5 };
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << traits<derived>::value << std::endl;

  std::cin.get();
}
```

There are scaling issues but I don't believe they're any better or worse than the alternative in the other question.

Comment: Thanks... It looks there is nothing simpler around, but these is at least is done with one line (and few headers)