# How can I locally redefine boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, boost, typedef

I have a class with function called `void deallocatorFunc(ClassA *p)` I want using templates make it possible to write `boost::shared_ptr< ClassA > ptr(new ClassA());` instead of `boost::shared_ptr< ClassA > ptr(new ClassA(), deallocatorFunc);`. I want it to spread on to my class and its inheritors. How to do such thing in C++? (I really need my peculiar destructor for that special class, while I want to keep super simple API).

Comment: Could you overload `operator delete` for your type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use specialization for your class and wrap the standard implementation. Here's a self-contained compilable example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

class A
{
   public:
   A() {
      cout << "Constructing A." << endl;
   };
   virtual ~A() {
      cout << "Destructing A." << endl;
   }
};

class B : public A
{
   public:
   B() {
      cout << "Constructing B." << endl;
   };
   virtual ~B() {
      cout << "Destructing B." << endl;
   }
};
class C
{
   public:
   C() {
      cout << "Constructing C." << endl;
   };
   virtual ~C() {
      cout << "Destructing C." << endl;
   }
};

void deallocatorFunc(A *p)
{
   cout << "Deallocator function." << endl;
   delete p;
};

namespace boost {
    template<> class shared_ptr<A> {
       private:
       shared_ptr<void> _ptr;
       public:
       shared_ptr(A* p) : _ptr(p, deallocatorFunc)
       {
       }
    };
}
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
   boost::shared_ptr<A> ptrA(new A());
   boost::shared_ptr<B> ptrB(new B());
   boost::shared_ptr<C> ptrC(new C());
}
```

**Output:**

> Constructing A.  Constructing A.  Constructing B.  Constructing C.
>   Destructing C.  Destructing B.  Destructing A.  Deallocator function.
>   Destructing A.

*Note*

As given, the specialization doesn't work for derived classes of A!

For that to work, you need more trickery:

[Template specialization based on inherit class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281725/template-specialization-based-on-inherit-class)

Comment: You're demonstrating explicit specialization, not partial specialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace boost {
    template<typename myclass> class shared_ptr {
    };
}
```

Enjoy your redefinition of boost::shared_ptr. Anything which includes the above code in a header will get *your* `shared_ptr` instead of boost's.

**Keep in mind this will not be compatible with code which includes boost on its own!!!**

Comment: Is it any how possible tojust overload/specialize boost shared_ptr  creation for one class type keeping it compatible with code which includes boost on its own?

Comment: @myWallJSON : No, but you could make your constructor private and force people to use factory functions to allocate objects on the freestore (the factory functions would use the correct semantics).

Comment: @ildjarn: of course it's possible, he just needs to override one template specialization of `shared_ptr` and copy through the remainder.

Comment: If you think that's true then you should elaborate more. I don't think it's true, but I don't know what you mean by "*override one template specialization of `shared_ptr` and copy through the remainder*" because that doesn't make much sense to me. (And how would whatever that is avoid violating the ODR?)

Comment: @ildjarn: The ODR applies to template instantiations, not template declarations. You may have a template where "if the parameter is `MyClass`, use this version, otherwise use the generic catch-all". See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm as a random off-the-web resource.

Comment: 1) An explicit specialization, as you seem to be advocating (I'm still not clear), is not a template at all. 2) _Instantiations_ of `boost::shared_ptr<ClassA>` in external code lacking said specialization will have different definitions than local code with the specialization -- this does violate the ODR.

Comment: @ildjarn: as I said, this is incompatible with code using the "real" `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: You also said "*of course it's possible*", so you're contradicting yourself yet again.

Comment: @ildjarn: I didn't mean the user code includes the boost headers. If they include your header *instead*, and of the remainder of the code could work (you can pass through the legitimate boost functionality).