# how to determine which class specialization is used?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template

```
template<class T>
class A
{
};
```

and one of its specialization

```
template<>
class A<B>
{
};
```

If C is a sub-class of B

```
class C : public B
{
};
```

Which instantiation is used for `A<C>`? If it uses the first one `A<T>`, how to let it use the second one `A<B>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary template will be used since `A<B>` is not a match for `A<C>`.  Look at this question for suggestions on how to make it work: [Template specialization based on inherit class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/281725/951890)

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename T, bool isB>
class AHelper {
  // generic implementation
};

template <typename T>
class AHelper<T, true> {
  // specialization for B
};

template <typename T>
class A : public AHelper<T, std::is_base_of<B, T>::value>
{};
```