# How to specialize implementation of a template class if T was derived from a specific base class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I want to specialize implementation of a template class if T was derived from a specific base class.

How can I do this?

In the code below, x.f() and y.f() should do different work.

I want to work not only for 'Derived' but also for all derived classes from Base.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

// If T not derived from Base:
template <typename T> class MyClass
{
public:
   void f()
   {
      std::cout << "NOT derived from Base";
   }
};

// If T derived from Base:
template <typename T> class MyClass
{
public:
   void f()
   {
      std::cout << "Derived from Base";
   }
};

int main()
{
   MyClass<int> x;
   MyClass<Derived> y;
   x.f();
   y.f();
}
```

Comment: Following may help : https://ideone.com/tlxtbs

Comment: More often than not what you **really** want to specialize templates based on the traits of the the parameter class, not based of the inheritance of the parameter. In which case...use traits helper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use following :

```
#include <type_traits>

//If T not derived from Base:
template<class T, class Enable = void> class MyClass
{
public:
   void f()
   {
      std::cout << "NOT derived from Base";
   }
};


template<typename T>
class MyClass<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type> 
{
 public:
   void f()
   {
      std::cout << "\nDerived from Base";
   }
};
```

See [***Here***](http://rextester.com/XTRD32076)

Comment: I want to work for all derived class not only 'Derived'.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/25934222/1132686 is simpler.